# Conditions for a quadratic equation to be positive?

Tags: quadratics

I was solving a problem in physics when I encountered this problem. I wanted to find the condition where the value of a quadratic equation is positive. Suppose the function is : $f(x) = Ax^2+Bx+C$ 
Then, I need to find the condition for which the function will give me positive value.Please Help!

Comment: There are two conditions : $A >0$ and $B^2-4AC<0$. They must be both satisfied.

Comment: Yeah I came across this but what i need to know is how to derive these conditions.

Comment: See https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-quadratics/alg-quadratic-inequalities/v/quadratic-inequalities-visual-explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can express

$$y = ax^2 + bx +c=  \frac{(2ax+b)^2 +4ac - b^2}{4a}$$

Now it is clear, $y$ is positive when $4a$ is positive and $4ac - b^2$ is positive.

Comment: Hey, I formatted your answer in MathJax for you (the edit will be visible shortly) I suggest you read a [basic MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as it is the standard for math formatting here and it makes math much more readable! Have a nice day

Comment: Easy Explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1,x_2$ be the solutions of $f(x)=0$.

Case 1: $x_1,x_2 \notin \mathbb R$. If $A>0$, then $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R.$ If $A<0$, then $f(x) <0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R.$

Case 2: $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$. We can assume that $x_1 \le x_2$. If $A>0$ , then $f(x)>0$  $ \iff x<x_1$ or $x>x_2$.
It is now your turn to investigate the situation if $A<0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate?